# Almacenar pdf con html2pdf en el servidor

Tags: php, html2pdf

Desearía saber cómo puedo almacenar un pdf generado por Html2pdf en mi servidor local.

Lo que he hecho es lo siguiente:

```
<?php
require './vendor/autoload.php';
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

if(isset($_POST['crear'])){
ob_start();
require_once 'prueba.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();

$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P', 'A4', 'es', 'true', 'UTF-8');

$html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
$html2pdf->output('http://direccion ip/cartas/prueba.pdf', "f");   
}
?>
```

Pero no funciona, ¿cuál puede ser la sintaxis correcta?

Comment: Sustituye el html2pdf por lo siguiente: $html2pdf->output('http://direccion ip/cartas/prueba.pdf'); creo que te sobra el último parametro del output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de realizar el ensayo y error logré encontrar la solución, para ello, comparto algunos ejemplos que pueden servir a las demás personas que han tenido el mismo error.

Para almacenarlo en el escritorio:

```
$html2pdf->output('/Users/nombre/Desktop/prueba.pdf', "f");
```

Para almacenarlo en el servidor xampp:

```
$html2pdf->output('/xampp/htdocs/cartas/docs/prueba.pdf', "f");
```